# Export list from RemoteApp Programs

Tags: powershell, remote, rds

Since I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2 Google wasn't helpful. What I need is an option to export (a list of) all "RemoteApp Programs". I'd prefer Powershell options/commands (V2 though), but all suggestions are welcome of course. I imported the remotedesktopservices module and I'm currently trying it via the RDS: drive, but at "RDS:\RemoteApp\RemoteAppProgramm> gci" the listing starts but is incredibly slow, like displaying one entry every 3-4 minutes. At this point I have to "kill" Powershell and start all over. Thank you!

Comment: Just use the built-in cmdlets to look at the registry for all installed apps. There are lots of examples of this all over the web.

Comment: There are in newer/later PS versions, but this is version 2.x. Unfortunately there aren't any and I can't import modules. I imported the mentioned "remotedesktopservices" module and that caused some issues. If I'm wrong, please correct me!

Answer (score 0):

Putting this here since it is too long for the comment section.

You can do this with PowerShell v2, by just using the .Net namespace. This is also documented/blogged about and shown all over the web. A quick search of your use case.

'[PowerShell v2 get a list of installed applications remotely](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powewrshell%20v2%20get%20list%20of%20installed%20applications%20remotely&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=powewrshell%20v2%20get%20list%20of%20installed%20applications%20remotely&sc=0-58&sk=&cvid=EC9F57CABC344FCA955E0FB31140F870)'

Example hits...

[Use PowerShell to Quickly Find Installed Software](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-quickly-find-installed-software)

[PowerShell: List and Export installed programs (Local or Remote)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34637.powershell-list-and-export-installed-programs-local-or-remote.aspx)

[Get the List of installed softwares on remote computers with PowerShell](http://vcloud-lab.com/entries/powershell/get-list-the-installed-softwares-on-remote-computers-with-powershell)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, but that's not quite what I'm looking for. Maybe I didn't explain myself correctly. In the "RemoteApp Manager" there is a section called "RemoteApp Programs". I need a way to export that list with all its details.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out and I feel stupid since it was kinda obvious. I simply selected all entries in "RemoteApp Program" and then (on the right side hand) I clicked "Export RemoteApp Settings" which creates a .tspub file. It basically an XML file (so I changed the extension to .xml) which I'm using now in Powershell to filter the info I need.